# How to find issue in XAML that causes code crash

Tags: silverlight

I wrote a Radio Button style.

When a page containing a Radio button, that has the style implementation I wrote. is shown I get crash and I don't know why.

After I examined the xaml more than 8 times - I found the bug.

But I still want to ask some important question ==> How can i find bugs like this in the future ?

There are no place to add 'breakpoints' in the code to stop the code and look if my input is wrong or to look for some algorithm flow.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I've had this problem multiple times as well, and the best way to find it is to remember what you just changed. But that means running the app more often and is quite annoying. I'm interested to see what answers you might get.